# If the proxy_factory.json address is not different across various chainIDs, is it impossible to retrieve the multisig wallet address?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I want to build a safe address on the base chain that is identical to the one I have on the ARB chain. I referred to this video tutorial: https://www.loom.com/share/ca34aabcd62747fb9fb89bd463b4c741. One of the steps is to verify if the contracts for different chainIDs are the same. So, I checked on this webpage: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-deployments/blob/main/src/assets/v1.3.0/proxy_factory.json.

The chainID for ARB is 42161.
The chainID for BASE is 8453.

They are not the same.
Does this mean I cannot recover my safe wallet address from the ARB chain on the base chain?"